# Find conditional probabilities using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm given a problem that explicitly tell me not to use `numpy` and `pandas` for this :

given a list of lists, each `sublist` will be of length 2 i.e. [[x,y],[p,q],[l,m]..[r,s]] consider its like a `matrix` of n rows and two columns

The first column F will contain only 5 unique values (F1, F2, F3, F4, F5)
The second column S will contain only 3 unique values (S1, S2, S3)
your task is to find

```
a. Probability of P(F=F1|S==S1), P(F=F1|S==S2), P(F=F1|S==S3)
b. Probability of P(F=F2|S==S1), P(F=F2|S==S2), P(F=F2|S==S3)
c. Probability of P(F=F3|S==S1), P(F=F3|S==S2), P(F=F3|S==S3)
d. Probability of P(F=F4|S==S1), P(F=F4|S==S2), P(F=F4|S==S3)
e. Probability of P(F=F5|S==S1), P(F=F5|S==S2), P(F=F5|S==S3)
Ex:
[[F1,S1],[F2,S2],[F3,S3],[F1,S2],[F2,S3],[F3,S2],[F2,S1],[F4,S1],[F4,S3],[F5,S1]]

a. P(F=F1|S==S1)=1/4, P(F=F1|S==S2)=1/3, P(F=F1|S==S3)=0/3
b. P(F=F2|S==S1)=1/4, P(F=F2|S==S2)=1/3, P(F=F2|S==S3)=1/3
c. P(F=F3|S==S1)=0/4, P(F=F3|S==S2)=1/3, P(F=F3|S==S3)=1/3
d. P(F=F4|S==S1)=1/4, P(F=F4|S==S2)=0/3, P(F=F4|S==S3)=1/3
e. P(F=F5|S==S1)=1/4, P(F=F5|S==S2)=0/3, P(F=F5|S==S3)=0/3
```

I wrote the following code for the above, however, I'm getting the following error, and I'm not sure what the problem is:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'
```

Also, the code I wrote seems to be very bad way of implementing the above problem, is there a better way ? if so, would request you to share it.

```
A = [['F1','S1'],['F2','S2'],['F3','S3'],['F1','S2'],['F2','S3'],['F3','S2'],['F2','S1'],['F4','S1'],['F4','S3'],['F5','S1']]

dictionary1 = {
 'F1S1':0,
 'F2S1':0,
 'F3S1':0,
 'F4S1':0,
 'F5S1':0,
 'F1S2':0,
 'F2S2':0,
 'F3S2':0,
 'F4S2':0,
 'F5S2':0,
 'F1S3':0,
 'F2S3':0,
 'F3S3':0,
 'F4S3':0,
 'F5S3':0,
}

dictionary2= {
 'S1':0,
 'S2':0,
 'S3':0
}

def compute_conditional_probabilities(A):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if(A[i][0]=='F1'& A[i][1]=='S1'):
            dictionary1['F1S1'] = dictionary1['F1S1'] +1
            dictionary2['S1'] = dictionary2['S1'] +1
        if(A[i][0]=='F1'&A[i][1]=='S2'):
            dictionary1['F1S2'] = dictionary1['F1S2'] +1
            dictionary2['S2'] = dictionary2['S2'] +1
        if(A[i][0]=='F1'&A[i][1]=='S3'):
            dictionary1['F1S3'] = dictionary1['F1S3'] +1
            dictionary2['S3'] = dictionary2['S3'] +1
        if(A[i][0]=='F2'&A[i][1]=='S1'):
            dictionary1['F2S1'] = dictionary1['F2S1'] +1
            dictionary2['S1'] = dictionary2['S1'] +1
        if(A[i][0]=='F2'&A[i][1]=='S2'):
            dictionary1['F2S2'] = dictionary1['F2S2'] +1
            dictionary2['S2'] = dictionary2['S2'] +1
        if(A[i][0]=='F2'&A[i][1]=='S3'):
            dictionary1['F2S3'] = dictionary1['F2S3'] +1
            dictionary2['S3'] = dictionary2['S3'] +1
        if(A[i][0]=='F3'&A[i][1]=='S1'):
            dictionary1['F3S1'] = dictionary1['F3S1'] +1
            dictionary2['S1'] = dictionary2['S1'] +1
        if(A[i][0]=='F3'&A[i][1]=='S2'):
            dictionary1['F3S2'] = dictionary1['F3S2'] +1
            dictionary2['S2'] = dictionary2['S2'] +1
        if(A[i][0]=='F3'&A[i][1]=='S3'):
            dictionary1['F3S3'] = dictionary1['F3S3'] +1
            dictionary2['S3'] = dictionary2['S3'] +1
        if(A[i][0]=='F4'&A[i][1]=='S1'):
            dictionary1['F4S1'] = dictionary1['F4S1'] +1
            dictionary2['S1'] = dictionary2['S1'] +1
        if(A[i][0]=='F4'&A[i][1]=='S2'):
            dictionary1['F4S2'] = dictionary1['F4S2'] +1
            dictionary2['S2'] = dictionary2['S2'] +1
        if(A[i][0]=='F4'&A[i][1]=='S3'):
            dictionary1['F4S3'] = dictionary1['F4S3'] +1
            dictionary2['S3'] = dictionary2['S3'] +1
        if(A[i][0]=='F5'&A[i][1]=='S1'):
            dictionary1['F5S1'] = dictionary1['F5S1'] +1
            dictionary2['S1'] = dictionary2['S1'] +1
        if(A[i][0]=='F5'&A[i][1]=='S2'):
            dictionary1['F5S2'] = dictionary1['F5S2'] +1
            dictionary2['S2'] = dictionary2['S2'] +1
        if(A[i][0]=='F5'&A[i][1]=='S3'):
            dictionary1['F5S3'] = dictionary1['F5S3'] +1
            dictionary2['S3'] = dictionary2['S3'] +1                                

compute_conditional_probabilities(A)

print('Probability of P(F=F1|S==S1)',(dictionary1['F1S1']/dictionary2['S1']))
```

Comment: why don't you change `&` to `and` ?

Comment: It worked, thanks. Also, there is typo in the code, it should be dictionary2  under dictionary1 inside the if statement. However, is there a better way to solve this question ?

Comment: If you encounter a typo in your question, you can edit your question to fix the typo.

Answer (score 0):

(*removed parts of answer that related to parts of code you fixed already*)

Note that when calling a dictionary, you don't have to pass the key name as a string - you can pass a variable that holds that value. for example, if `d` is a dictionary and `k` is a variable equal to `1`, you can pass `d[k]` instead of `d[1]`. Using this, and the fact that you can "add" strings together to concatenate them (e.g. 'a'+'b' = 'ab'), you can re-write your `compute_conditional_probabilities` function as:

```
def compute_conditional_probabilities(A):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        k = A[i][0]+A[i][1]
        dictionary1[k] += 1
        dictionary2[A[i][1]] += 1
```

See if this works, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
A = [['F1', 'S1'], ['F2', 'S2'], ['F3', 'S3'], ['F1', 'S2'], ['F2', 'S3'], ['F3', 'S2'], ['F2', 'S1'], ['F4', 'S1'], ['F4', 'S3'], ['F5', 'S1']]

dictionary1 = {
'F1S1': 0,
'F2S1': 0,
'F3S1': 0,
'F4S1': 0,
'F5S1': 0,
'F1S2': 0,
'F2S2': 0,
'F3S2': 0,
'F4S2': 0,
'F5S2': 0,
'F1S3': 0,
'F2S3': 0,
'F3S3': 0,
'F4S3': 0,
'F5S3': 0,
}

dictionary2 = {
'S1': 0,
'S2': 0,
'S3': 0
}


def compute_conditional_probabilites(A):
    for i in range(len(A)):
       k = A[i][0] + A[i][1]
       dictionary1[k] += 1
       dictionary2[A[i][1]] += 1

compute_conditional_probabilites(A)
print('Probability of P(F=F1|S==S1)', (dictionary1['F4S3']/dictionary2['S3']))
```

Output

```
Probability of P(F=F1|S==S1) 0.3333333333333333
```

Comment: Thanks Arun, got the desired output. However, is there a better way to solve this question ?

Comment: @HemanthRavavarapu there is - you can avoid the `if` statements altogether, see below.

Comment: @Itamar Mushkin, Great, updated the code with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
listCombine = []
listDen = []

def compute_conditional_probabilites(A):
for i in range(len(A)):
        k = A[i][0]+A[i][1]
        listDen.append(A[i][1])
        listCombine.append(k)
        print(listCombine)
        print(listDen)
```

in above function i just combine A[0]and A[1] and put in a list listCombine and A[1] in list listDen

```
A = [['F1','S1'],['F2','S2'],['F3','S3'],['F1','S2'],['F2','S3'],['F3','S2'],['F2','S1'],['F4','S1'],['F4','S3'],['F5','S1']]
compute_conditional_probabilites(A)

print("conditional probability P(F=F1|S==S1)=1/4-----",(listCombine.count('F1S1')/listDen.count('S1')))
```

I count the no of the items in the list and found the conditional probability, I don't it is the best way or not

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [['F1','S1'],['F2','S2'],['F3','S3'],['F1','S2'],['F2','S3'],['F3','S2'],['F2','S1'],['F4','S1'],['F4','S3'],['F5','S1']]
from fractions import Fraction
def values(F,S):
    num=0
    den=0
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if(A[i][1]==S):
            den=den+1
            if(A[i][0]==F):
               num=num+1
    print('P(F={}|S=={})='.format(F,S), Fraction(num,den))

for k in ['F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4', 'F5']:
    for m in ['S1', 'S2', 'S3']:
        values(k,m)
```

Try this, worked well for me. coders are welcome to improve this.

Answer (score 0):

it can be done without fraction as well

```
def values(F,S):
    num=0
    den=0
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if(A[i][1]==S):
            den=den+1
            if(A[i][0]==F):
                num=num+1
    print('P(F={}|S=={})={}/{}'.format(F, S, str(num), str(den)))

for k in ['F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4', 'F5']:
    for m in ['S1', 'S2', 'S3']:
        values(k,m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to generate the dictionary with A as the list of lists

```
for i in range (len(A)):
   dictionary1.update({A[i][0]+A[i][1]: 0})
   dictionary2.update({A[i][1]: 0})
print(dictionary1)
print(dictionary1)here
```